# Real time combine data from multiple worksheets into a summary worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in multiple Data worksheets that want to combine into Summary worksheet.
When user update data in any Data worksheet, it will copy information automatically to Summary worksheet.

For example

**(Input) Data worksheet1**

```
 |   A   |    B   |   C   |
    Cat      Red     Male
    Dog     Green   Female
```

**(Input) Data worksheet2**

```
 |   A   |    B   |   C   |
  Monkey   Brown    Male
    Ant     Blue     Male
   Bird     White   Female
```

**(Output) Summary Worksheet**

```
 |   A   |    B   |   C   |
    Cat      Red     Male
    Dog     Green   Female
  Monkey    Brown    Male
    Ant     Blue     Male
   Bird     White   Female
```

Right now my code running okay with one data worksheet. But when I try to switch to work on another data worksheet, the data on summary worksheet will not correct. It also has some errors when I delete all information or when I change the code (I need to reopen it).

Here is my code

ThisWorkBook

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set ActWS = WB.ActiveSheet
Set MainWS = WB.Worksheets("Main")

ActWSPreLastRow = ActWS.Cells(ActWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MainWSPreLastRow = MainWS.Cells(MainWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

Module

```
Public WB As Workbook
Public ActWS As Worksheet
Public MainWS As Worksheet
Public ActWSPreLastRow As Long
Public ActWSStoredLastRow As Long
Public MainWSPreLastRow As Long
Public MainWSStoredLastRow As Long
Public MainWSEndLastRow As Long
Public I As Long

Public Sub DoCopy()

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set ActWS = WB.ActiveSheet
Set MainWS = WB.Worksheets("Main")

ActWSPreLastRow = ActWS.Cells(ActWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MainWSPreLastRow = MainWS.Cells(MainWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

I = MainWSStoredLastRow + (ActWSPreLastRow - ActWSStoredLastRow)

MainWS.Range("A" & MainWSStoredLastRow + 1, "AQ" & I).Value = _
ActWS.Range("A" & ActWSStoredLastRow + 1, "AQ" & ActWSPreLastRow).Value

MainWSPreLastRow = MainWS.Cells(MainWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub

Public Sub StoreOld()
ActWSStoredLastRow = ActWSPreLastRow
MainWSStoredLastRow = MainWSPreLastRow

End Sub
```

Other worksheets

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A5:AQ1000")) Is Nothing Then
    Call StoreOld
    Call DoCopy
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Create a simple Microsoft query like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119513/comparing-two-excel-sheets-using-vba/30119739#30119739 - `Join both` section. Then simply refresh it when needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Microsoft Query** to the rescue:

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM [Sheet1$] 
UNION ALL
SELECT A,B,C FROM [Sheet2$]
```

`Data->From Other Sources->Microsoft Query` or feel free to use [my Add-In](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/).

Then simply refresh the Query when needed (via 1 line VBA or right-click on the table and click refresh).

### Details

Assuming that the structure of `Sheet1` & `Sheet2` are:

(Input) Data worksheet1 (with row numbers)

```
 1    |   A   |    B   |   C   |
 2       Cat      Red     Male
 3       Dog     Green   Female
```

(Input) Data worksheet2 (with row numbers)

```
 1    |   A   |    B   |   C   |
 2     Monkey   Brown    Male
 3       Ant     Blue     Male
 4      Bird     White   Female
```

**Then:**

1. Create a new worksheet (Sheet3)
2. Create the Query with the SQL above.

If you want to add a condition add a `WHERE` clause to one or both of the `SELECTs`

Comment: I don't know much about SQL or Microsoft Query. My data has many row for header, is it possible to do that?

Comment: Just use the SQL above. Yes it is possible this is the most efficient way

Comment: There will be many users on this file and I think their skills is not high enough to handle this task daily.

Comment: The query is created once and updated just like a pivot table or you can make a simple refresh button. The users won't even know if its the macro or the query in the backend

Comment: I see... So do you have any information that I can learn more about this. I already tried but can't figure out how to config it-- for example to set a condition where is the first row of data.

Comment: Sure. Basically the first row is always the header so if you name your columns "A", "B", "C" you can reference them simply by the cell value. Here is a quick an easy tutorial http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/microsoft-query.html Here are the basics on SQL: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I still have a question. If I cannot set the first row to be the header, what should I do? or should I create a new column and add some text to use it for WHERE clause

Comment: Why can't you add a row as a header at the top like in your example? I think MS Query assumes the top row is the Header always.

Comment: OK, I tried to set only first row as header and it works fine on office 2013. But other users in my company still using office 2007 and it not working (no data update on refreshing)